# Automatically adding a number to each image in a directory

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I want to display a number on top of each image, for all image files in a directory. In other words, each image is modified to contain a box containing a number. How can I automate this?

Comment: Hi! While its fine to ask a question to post a GOOD answer, both your posts are too short and lack essential detail. (e.g. what does "add a number on top" mean?) Good answers don't consist only of code but they explain what happens and how that solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I improved it based on your comment.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10. I've updated the answer to work with both new and really old versions.

Answer (score -2):

This bash-script does that. It uses imagemagick. Install imagemagick by `apt-get install imagemagick` on Ubuntu and Debian systems, and a similar yum command on Fedora.
The trick is to increase a counter for each image, and use that value when writing the label on each image.
All commands used by the script have existed in Ubuntu/Debian since at least 2016, and works with Ubuntu 21.10 as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p out #creates an output directory called 'out'
i=0
ls -1 *.jpg *.JPEG *.jpeg *.JPG 2>/dev/null|while read image
do
  number=$(printf "%02d" $i)
  convert "$image" -fill black -undercolor '#FFFFFF' -pointsize 25 -gravity northwest -annotate +10+10 "$number" "out/$image"
  ((i=i+1))
done
```

Comment: Debian and Fedora as well as versions of Ubuntu that have reached the end of life are off topic here.